# Google Cloud Vision API limit and usage

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-vision

In my project I need to use the Google Vision API in order to know if an image uploaded by the user is rated as adult content or not.

In their documentation page we have a pricing table [Google Vision API Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing) in which we can see there is a free plan in which you have some limits. In order to start using this I needed to join the free trial and set a billing account.

My questions are the following:

1. When the limits are reached, am I going to be billed by Google? Or the service will be unavailable until I accept to be billed for that?
2. As I have joined to a free trial, is this API usage limited to the trial period (60 days), or is it free (limited) even when the trial period has ended?

Comment: Google is not going to charge you until you agree to be charged.    So if you hit the limit things are just going to stop working, until you agree.   You should be able to see the limit in Developer console.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks, and regarding the trial period? is this service available for free even when the trial period has ended?

Comment: I haven't been able to find out any information on that.   I dug though there documentation quite extensively.   I did share your question with a few people who may know see if you don't get a better response then my educated guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the limits are reached, am I going to be billed by Google? Or the
>   service will be unavailable until I accept to be billed for that?

When you reach the limit the service stop working. Google doesn't charge you, as DalmTo said

> As I have joined to a free trial, is this API usage limited to the
>   trial period (60 days), or is it free (limited) even when the trial
>   period has ended?

For Cloud Vision API, after the free trial, the features to analyze the images are free with a cap of 1000 units/months.
[Google Cloud Vision API Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing)